# org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to connect to Cassandra DB using JDBC driver:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://10.11.15.242:9042/edgeview");
```

I am unable to connect to Cassandra. It always give below errors:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
```

I have added below Libraries:

```
Cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar
Cassandra-thrift-1.2.6.jar
Cassandra-clientutil-1.2.6.jar
libthrift-0.9.0.jar
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I vote for reopenning this question, as error is quite unique and given answer below reveals the only one reason for this error (what helped me in my case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://10.11.15.242:9042/edgeview");
```

So 9042 is the port for the native binary protocol connection, and 9160 is for Thrift.

You need to figure out if you are connecting via Thrift or Native, and use the appropriate port.  Given your error message, it sounds like JDBC Cassandra uses Thrift, so you may need to specify 9160 as your port.

Of course, connecting via Thrift has been deprecated, and is even disabled by default in Cassandra 2.2+.

Comment: So can you help me if I want to connect without using thrift? As if I do not use thrift, then it gives me cross language error...

Comment: Can you help me for some alternative way then?

Comment: I vote for reopenning this question, as error is quite unique and given answer below reveals the only one reason for this error (what helped me in my case).

Comment: How does one connect to Cassandra 3? What driver should I use?

Comment: @KaMok You should use the DataStax Java driver, and they have connection examples out in their Git repo: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-examples/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/examples/basic/ReadCassandraVersion.java